# Android: adding a red arrow to a picture programmatically

Tags: java, android

The user will be taking a picture of som playing cards, and the app will determine what card and where it should be placed to continue. Once this is calculated, i would like to have an arrow from the cards position to where it should be placed for the user to see.

Is this even possible? and where would i be able to learn about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked: "Is this even possible? and where would i be able to learn about it?"

For your first question: Yes.

For your second question: It depends on what exactly you want to do: Do you need to automatically analyze the picture to identify the card? You can start researching for OpenCV.

Comment: Yes, i knew about openCV and will be using that to analyse the picture, will it also be able to edit the picture?

Comment: One quick google search and i got the answer i needed, Thank you!